# Click an element inside fieldset using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

I need to click on a div element (highlighted in blue color) which is inside a fieldset

I tried:

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='export-format-container-test-only reportsExportFormat reportsExportDialog']/fieldset//input[@class='slds-form-element']")))
```

I am unable to locate the element using this way. How could I achieve it?

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Comment: @Prophet Sorry! that page requires my username and password.

Comment: OK, I understand. Can you share the entire XML of the page? preferably as a text

Comment: @Prophet I have attached picture with full XMl and I need to access the highlighted element.

Comment: I can't see `slds-form-element` class name in the highlighted `input`

Comment: @Prophet slds-form-element is fieldset class. You can find it where the fieldset is defined. I need to make a click on 'slds-visual-picker......' class

Comment: I see. Can you paste the XML as a text, not as a picture? it's extremely uncomfortable to use it. Impossible to make search, to validate locators etc...

Comment: @Sriram : Check out my updated answer hope that will resolve your query!

Answer (score 0):

Your `xpath` seems wrong. Try the following `xpath`. This should identify the div element inside `fieldset` tag

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//fieldset//div[@class='export-format-container-test-only reportsExportFormat reportsExportDialog']")))
```

Or you can use simple this xpath

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-aura-class='reportsExportVisualPickerOption']")))
```

---

**Update:**

To click on radio button, you can simply click on the `label` element, no need to click on span.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//fieldset[.//div[@class='export-format-container-test-only reportsExportFormat reportsExportDialog']]//label[@for='data-export']"))).click()
```